# How to run script in mvn as test

Tags: maven, testing, jenkins

I would like to have the following scenario in Maven/Jenkins:

- Run test scripts (bash/shell)
- when the script exited with a problem (an error), then the Maven  build on Jenkins should be on `UNSTABLE` and not `FAILURE` status

**Question**: How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can run scripts in Maven using the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin) and its [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal.

If you want to run the script during the `test` phase, then you can bind an execution of the plugin to it as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-test-script</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable><!-- configure here your script .sh/.cmd --> </executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument><!-- configure here arguments, if any --></argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory><!-- configure here PWD, if required --></workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that you can also configure different successful exit codes via the `successCodes` configuration entry.

If the script fails, then the build will fail. However, you can change this behavior on the Jenkins build via the [Jenkins Text Finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) and configure it as Post-build Action:

- You should set-up a regular expression which could be found as part of the Maven build output on Jenkins. As example, the regex `.*Script Failed.*` would match the string `Script Failed` printed by the script in such a case. So the build will actually fail, however we can change its status on Jenkins (but not on Maven)
- You should check the option `Unstable if found` which will convert the status of the build from `FAILED` to `UNSTABLE`

As per documentation of the `Unstable if found` option:

> Use this option to set build unstable instead of failing the build.

You can see an example of such a configuration in the image below:
[image: Jenkins Text Finder Plugin example]

As such, you would have a script executed in the `test` phase as you desired, the Maven build would fail if the script did so but the Jenkins build would change its status according to your configuration of the Text Finder plugin.

Also note: if you want Maven not to fail in case the script did, you can play with the `successCodes` as mentioned above and still make the Jenkins build change its status to `UNSTABLE` according to the same configuration of the Text Finder plugin. Hence different combinations are possible.

Comment: @Azriel did this approach help out?

Comment: I gave up and decided to run the tests from JUNIT